# is r-x file considered read only or not?

Tags: bash, filesystems, filenames, root, readonly

A file is considered "read-only" if reading the file is
allowed but writing to the file is not permitted.

What if the file has the following permissions (r and x)

**root r-x file_name.xls**

Is this file considered read only or not? Given that it has permissions to be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this file considered read only or not? Given that it has permissions to be executed

Yes, it is to be considered *read only*. Executing a file doesn't require write permission, only read permission, so there's no conflict in that combination of settings.